# Building dynamic widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

Could you please help with how we can build a dynamic list of widgets instead of building cards(containers or widgets) for example one by one manually? Using the ListView.build or other methods? What is the best way?

I spent a day trying and researching. Instead of adding 3 cards(or other objects with multiple properties), I am trying to build a method or a function that will build each card(object) based on the list(and length) and then insert all the card built automatically in the [].

I've been trying to achieve it, but when I add it to [] there are some problems, probably because of the wrong types or maybe I am doing something horribly wrong? And not sure if it's the best(if correct at all) way of doing it?

```
List entries = ['one', 'two', 'three3'];

Widget buildListView() {
  return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
        );
      });
}
```

Comment: are you trying to create a list of widgets directly and want to pass it as a whole to the listview builder?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
 ///construct the list of dynamic widgets as per your requirement.
 final listWidgets = [Text("one"), Text("two"), Text("three")];


 ///pass the widgets to the listview builder.
 return ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemCount: listWidgets.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        child: listWidgets[index],
      );
    });
    });
```